# How to understand this hermitian vector bundle?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

I am reading Huybrechts's complex geometry. In page 166, he gives the definition of hermitian structure.

Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle over a real manifold $M$. An hermitian structure $h$ on $E\to M$ is an hermitian scalar product $h_{x}$ on each fibre $E(x)$ which depend smoothly on $x$. This pair $(E,h)$ is called an hermitian vector bundle.

This definition is very natural. However, then he gives an example which make me confused.

Let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle and let $s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{k}$ be global sections generating $L$ every where. Picking a trivialization $\phi: L_{U}\cong U\times \mathbb{C}$ around a point $x$. Then one defines an hermitian structure on $L$ by

$$h(t)=\frac{|\phi(t)|^{2}}{\sum |\phi(s_{i})|^2}.$$

where $t$ is a point in the fiber $L(x)$.

I am very confused. We know $L$ is a line bundle, so $L(x)$ is an complex one dimensional vector space. So if we want to find a hermitian metric on $L(x)$, it is enough to find a positive number for it. Thus we should construct a funtion $h:=h(x)$ which is a smooth function on $U$. I do not know why he uses $h(t)$. $h(t)$ is a function on the fiber $L(x)$, not the function on the manifold.

One explantion is he may want to refer $h(x)=\frac{|\phi(t)|^{2}}{\sum |\phi(s_{i})|^2},$ where $t$ is a point in $L(x)$. This is also strange, since then this hermitian metric will depond on the choice of $t$ and hence it is not natural.

Could you tell me how to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ is an arbitrary section of $L$ representing the germ.  Now you use the local trivialization $\phi$ to define $h(t)\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\frac{\lvert\phi_2(t(\cdot))\rvert^2}{\sum_i\lvert\phi_2(s_i(\cdot))\rvert^2}
$$
where $\phi_2$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-coordinate of $\phi\colon L\vert_U\to U\times\mathbb{C}$ (at the appropriate point of $U$).

Comment: Could you explain "Let $t$  be an arbitrary section of $L$ representing the germ’’ more precisely ? I could not understand it well.

Comment: Any point in the fibre $L(x)$ can be extended to a (smooth) section of $L$ on some neighbourhood $U\ni x$ (WLOG assume $U$ is also a trivializing neighbourhood) and so with a slight abuse of notation we can also use the same letter $t$ to denote this section.  Then smoothness of $h$ is immediate, and it is easy to see this is an inner product on each fibre.

Comment: But it seems in this way, then inner product will depend on the $t$. If we choose different point on $L(x)$, then we will get different metric, right?

Comment: No, this is $h(t)=\langle t,t\rangle$ so must depend on $t$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I think I just misunderstood the author’s meaning. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user10354138 could you elaborate on '' Any point in the fibre $L(x)$ can be extended to a (smooth) section of L on some neighborhood $U\ni x$ '' i need some reference or some clarification to why is this true.